# My selenium test is not working, where is the issue?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I want to use selenium grid, and this is my step:

1. Start Selenium Grid Hub:
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -ro hub
2. Start Selenium Node:
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -ro node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome
3. Java Code:

```
    public class TestGrid {
        static WebDriver driver;
        static String nodeUrl;

        @Before
        public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
            nodeUrl = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
            capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);
        }

        @Test
        public void simpleTest() {
            driver.get("https://www.edureka.co");
            Assert.assertEquals("Instructor Led Online Courses with 24x7 On-Demand Support | Edureka",
                    driver.getTitle());
        }

        @After
        public void afterTest() {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

But when I run this in IDE, I found the Test part never arrived and seemed at before step, just stuck at last step:

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);
```

I only see from console:

```
Oct 05, 2019 10:08:15 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
```

And in selenim hub console:

```
10:09:16.438 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platform: MAC, version: }
10:09:16.443 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=952f43b8-f264-48b3-aa6f-eff6ff59b16e, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome, platformName=MAC, platform=MAC}
```

Then never arrive at Test part

Please help to tell what's is going on here

I am using mac, so `chromedriver --version` is giving:

```
ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0b556f8030b65b953dce96503217-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#442})
```

I run this command inside the same folder as the selenium-server-standaralon-3.141.jar folder And this is the error for java junit:

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, version=, platform=MAC}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
>   Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'Franks-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.0.103', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
>   Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

I followed instruction as below, but when starting java junit, I got error from selenium server hub console:

```
Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platform: MAC}
10:30:12.334 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=4b8d38ff-8be6-4894-8c17-8fe334c7c3bc, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5, platformName=MAC, platform=MAC}
10:30:28.926 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Failed to connect to /10.1.3.246:14786
org.openqa.grid.internal.exception.NewSessionException: Error forwarding the request Failed to connect to /10.1.3.246:14786
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.forwardNewSessionRequestAndUpdateRegistry(RequestHandler.java:94)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:114)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.Driver
```

I saw this error after I copied chromedriver into the same folder as the selenium jar folder.

And in Java console, I saw this:

```
Oct 08, 2019 10:30:12 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Oct 08, 2019 10:31:28 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Oct 08, 2019 10:32:44 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, platform=MAC}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'my.local', ip: '10.1.2.137', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
    at com.datavisor.e2e.TestGrid.setup(TestGrid.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

maybe it is version issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Junit? If so, Check Junit error trace for below error.

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'

If this is the error you are getting then,

I believe your browser session is never created while executing - Looks like you do not have driver executable on node machine. Keep driver executable (chromedriver.exe if you are using chrome browser - choose appropriate driver version which supports your browser's version) in same folder with selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59

Alternatively try adding -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver parameter when starting the node. Your complete command will be,

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

You command is `-ro` maybe you mean `-role`.

Try this step:

1. Open command line:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
```

If successful, you will get this log:

```
[Hub.start] - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
[Hub.start] - Nodes should register to http://somethingIP:4444/grid/register/
[Hub.start] - Clients should connect to http://somethingIP:4444/wd/hub
```

2. Open another command line (or new tab):

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

If successful, you will get this log:

```
The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
```

[Documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#hub-configuration)

**Note:**

Collect the `chromedriver` and selenium `.jar` together in same folder. If not, change this config `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver` to `=fullPath/chromedriver`

Try the below code:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class TestGrid {
    private RemoteWebDriver driver;
    private DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    private String nodeUrl;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        nodeUrl = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);   
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
        driver.get("https://www.edureka.co");
        Assert.assertEquals("Instructor-Led Online Training with 24X7 Lifetime Support | Edureka", driver.getTitle());
    }

    @After
    public void afterTest() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.